# Application freezes when user doesn't enter any search value in RadGridView of telerik filter search in WPF

Tags: c#, telerik, freeze, radgridview

In WPF Application freezes when the user doesn't enter any search value in RadGridView of telerik filter search.
I'm using radgridview and each column has a filter control for searching when user doesn't enter a value for search it completely freezes until the mouse cursor goes outside of the application!
do you have any solution?
because I can't access to the filter button for disabling it until the user enters value!

I expect to not freeze.